# PHP to update existing MySQL row or insert a new one (confused about UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY )

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-update

I'm trying to code a pretty straightforward updater which can update/create a number of rows in a MySQL table, but I've definitely gone wrong somewhere. Here's what the table, `service`, looks like:

```
+---------+----+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| auto_id | id | number     | enlisted    | poe                |
+---------+----+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|      27 | 20 |            | 18.01.1916  | Newcastle, NSW     |
|      28 | 21 | 3088       | 31.07.1915  | Liverpool, NSW     |
|      29 | 21 |            | 19.05.1919  |                    |
|      30 | 22 |            | 10.1916     | 2 MD               |
|      31 | 23 | 1703       | 18.02.1916  | Melbourne          |
|      32 | 24 | 7683       | 13.09.1917  | West Maitland, NSW |
+---------+----+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

`auto_id` is the auto-incrementing primary key. `id` is the ID of a soldier in another table (all the IDs are unique). As you can see, soldier #21 has two service records. My problem is that in my (ugly, unwieldy) PHP code, when I try and edit a soldier to add a service record,  it simply adds new rows, both for the old record (which is being updated) and the new one. Here's the PHP:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($serviceArray); $i++) {
    $currentIDQuery = mysql_query("SELECT id from servicemen WHERE linkname='$target'");
    $currentID = mysql_fetch_row($currentIDQuery);
    $sqlService = "INSERT INTO service ".
                  "(id,number,enlisted,poe,unit,rank,place,casualties,awards,discharged,final_fate,cemetery,memorial)".
                  "VALUES('".$currentID[0]."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['number']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['enlisted']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['poe']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['unit']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['rank']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['place']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['casualties']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['awards']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['dis']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['final']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['cem']."', '".$serviceArray[$i]['mem']."')".
                  "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number='".$serviceArray[$i]['number']."', enlisted='".$serviceArray[$i]['enlisted']."', poe='".$serviceArray[$i]['poe']."', unit='".$serviceArray[$i]['unit']."', rank='".$serviceArray[$i]['rank']."', place='".$serviceArray[$i]['place']."', casualties='".$serviceArray[$i]['casualties']."', awards='".$serviceArray[$i]['awards']."', discharged='".$serviceArray[$i]['dis']."', final_fate='".$serviceArray[$i]['final']."', cemetery='".$serviceArray[$i]['cem']."', memorial='".$serviceArray[$i]['mem']."'";
    $retservice = mysql_query( $sqlService, $conn );
    if (!$retservice){
        die('Could not enter service data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

As far as I can make out, my problem is that the code will give a new `auto_id` whatever else it does. The `DUPLICATE KEY` it needs to be looking at is `id`, but there can be multiple identical values in there.

Answer (score 0):

For the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` action to be performed, there would need to be a `UNIQUE KEY` on the table (in addition to the `auto_id` column). The `INSERT` action has to cause a "duplicate key" error.

The `UNIQUE KEY` could be on a combination of columns, for example, in the sample data, `(id,enlisted)` appears to be unique. (I'm just guessing at what combination of columns uniquely identify a row.)

Comment: Unfortunately, `id` is not unique because there may be multiple rows with the same `id` (as above), and `enlisted` can unfortunately also repeat. Nothing except for `auto_id` is guaranteed to be unique...

EDIT: Or are you saying that the _combination_ of two columns can prove a row's uniqueness? Then that could well work...

Comment: No, unfortunately all columns except `auto_id` have duplicate values, so the database won't let me set up unique keys.

Comment: Yes, a _combination_ of columns can be declared to be UNIQUE. Absent a UNIQUE KEY constraint, an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` will always perform the INSERT action; the ON DUPLICATE KEY action won't ever be performed. If you were going to update a row, how would you _identify_ the row to be updated? If the SELECT to find a row returns multiple rows, how do you decide which row to update?